# Is the use of direct-expansion split systems to heat or cool exit enclosures permitted under the US model building Codes?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, hvac, standards, architecture

Most multistory buildings have enclosed exit stairways *somewhere* within them to provide safe egress from their non-discharge floors.  In a building that relies on hydronic heating/cooling, steam heating, or direct (resistance) electrical heating, the US model building Codes are rather clear that the heating/cooling equipment for the stair can live within the stair enclosure, in addition to having the ventilation equipment for that stair enclosure placed within the stair enclosure, connected directly to outside air.

This is as per the penetration rules in NFPA 101 7.1.3.2.1(10), which explicitly permit steam and water heating and cooling lines to serve the stairshaft in addition to electrical conduits, as well as IBC 1023.6 point 2, which permits exit stair ventilation equipment (in my case, a "single room" or "decentralized" type HRV or ERV in addition to an air handler/indoor unit) to be located within the stair enclosure.  Furthermore, the IBC's definition of ventilation includes means for supplying *conditioned* air to the space being ventilated, which supports interpreting 1023.6 point 2 to permit the placement of an air handler dedicated to an exit enclosure within that exit enclosure.

However, it seems to me that this argument falls down as soon as you provision direct-expansion air conditioning to the exit enclosure using a traditional split-system architecture.  This is due to NFPA 101 7.1.3.2.1(10) *not* permitting refrigerant lines to enter stairshfts, the *Handbook* commentary stating that 7.1.3.2.1(10) is intended to be a comprehensive list of permitted exit enclosure penetrations, and IMC 1109.2.3 prohibiting refrigerant lines from entering exit enclosures (exit passageways and exit stairs).

This, however, has the effect of forcing the air handler for the exit enclosure to be moved outside the exit enclosure, or to be migrated into a unitary system such as a through-the-wall or rooftop terminal type unit.  However, through-the-wall and packaged terminal units struggle with unwanted air leaks between the unit chassis and the wall sleeve, and RTUs have efficiency issues as well due to the entire unit living outside, forcing ducts to penetrate walls into exterior space.  Furthermore, there may not be adjacent indoor spaces available to house said air handler if it is desired to place it indoors.  Even if such spaces are available, that requires fire dampers on the duct penetrations thru the stairshaft as well as shaft-rated construction around the ducts *and* the air handler itself, which makes maintenance access to said air handler much more difficult.

This leaves me wondering: is it the intent of the model Codes to prohibit exit enclosures from being served by direct-expansion air handlers (split system indoor units) located within them?  It seems to me that the combination of a small ductless mini-split heat pump and a distributed-type HRV or ERV would provide an inexpensive way to fully service an exit enclosure in a fashion that's compatible with a low-load, high-efficiency building design, yet on their face, the IMC's refrigeration rules seem to apply to *all* split refrigeration systems, from a one-ton minisplit heat pump to a massive supermarket's remote chiller system, despite the vast difference in risk between the two.  Furthermore, hydronic and steam lines can leak too; worse yet, some heating systems that are allowed, such as one-pipe steam radiators, are more prone to fluids leakage during common malfunction conditions (any sort of stuck radiator vent on a one-pipe system will cause the radiator in question to spit cruddy water on a regular basis) than modern direct-expansion split systems ever are.

Comment: I am not an HVAC guy but have two questions: 1) Isn't the heat pump requires cooling and be installed outdoor? 2) Are you talking about units on the ceiling, or on anywhere of the stairway?

Comment: @r13 -- on a ceiling or a wall, and i'm referring to the *indoor unit* of the heatpump as obviously the outdoor unit will live outside

Comment: I think it is prohibited to have any obstruction on the stairway, and anything, other than sprinklers, that will spill or emit dangerous substances. Are you sure your ideas have no such concerns?

Comment: @r13 -- you can put a steam radiator in an exit stairwell, from what I can tell -- those things can spit a whole mess of hot water and gunk if they malfunction!

Comment: I've seen steam pipes/boilers explosion in industrial facilities, but not in general buildings, for which the installation tends to be the low-pressure type, and meet special requirements for safety.

Comment: @r13 -- this isn't an explosion per se, just the radiator vent on a one-pipe system malfunctioning and spitting hot, cruddy water out instead of air

Comment: I am not arguing with you. Can you cite a few historical cases for example to strengthen your position, so others might follow the leads to provide responses.

Comment: @r13 -- of radiator vents malfunctioning? [This troubleshooting piece](https://heatinghelp.com/systems-help-center/spitting-or-hissing-air-vents/) describes why it happens -- it's a relatively common phenomenon for one-pipe steam vents to exhibit, but in most cases, the worst problem it poses is making a mess on the wall unless you're right next to the radiator when it happens

Comment: Yes. I am suggesting to make it your focusing point in questioning the Code rejection on the types of equipment you have mentioned - why the differential treatment if proven equally safe/unsafe in a confined/egress space.

Comment: Assuming your research is correct, then yes it is to prevent you from placing an evaporator in the stairwell.  DX isn't just split units, it is typical window units as well.  The whys of building codes is way way way out of scope for us engineers and frankly is likely to have more to do with propping up certain businesses than sound safety policy.

Comment: @TigerGuy -- I fail to see where the NFPA 101 and IMC prohibitions on refrigerant line penetrations and runs, respectively, in exit enclosures apply to fully packaged equipment (PTAC, TTW, window units) as there are no lines under the jurisdiction of the building codes in that case.  (This is based on IMC 1101.2's text about self-contained, listed refrigeration appliances being deemed to meet the design requirements of the IMC if installed IAW manufacturer instructions, mostly)

Comment: Then your sources do not prohibit direct expansion units so don't say that they do.

Comment: @TigerGuy -- they prohibit direct expansion *split systems*, which is what I'm interested in. Clarified the post slightly

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but 7.1.3.2.1(9)(f) in the 2021 editions of NFPA 101 allows "Water or steam piping necessary for the heating or cooling of the exit enclosure." It seems pretty clear to me that this would support any of the air handler types you mentioned, as long as they are plumbed with a chilled water loop, not direct expansion style with a refrigerant.

Comment: @Ethan48 -- yeah, the rub is that chilled water in particular isn't an option for small-scale, IncDev style buildings (good luck finding a central water chiller in the sub-5-ton capacity range)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sure. And you have to climate control the exit stair enclosure even in such a small building? It's fairly common in my part of the world for egress stairs to have no heating or cooling.

Comment: @Ethan48 -- at the very least, keep it from freezing up, and cooling it is probably a good idea as well -- I'm in a part of the country that isn't blessed with a mild coastal climate :)  I suppose one could accomplish the former with resistive baseboard-type heat but that's not a cheap way to turn kWh into BTU